# Не работает загрузка файлов Asp.Net MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, mvc, загрузка

Я новичок в Asp.Net и в веб разработке в целом.Ни как не могу справиться с задачей загрузки изображений, перепробовал все способы доступные в интернете.Один из примеров,который я использовал:
Контроллер:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase upload)
{
    if(upload!=null)
    {

        string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(upload.FileName);



        upload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Files/" + fileName));
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Представление:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new {enctype="multipart/form-data"}))
{
    <input type="file" name="upload" /><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Загрузить" />
}
```

При нажатии на кнопку загрузить,останавливается запуск и браузер пишет: "Страница не доступна".При загрузке файла в базу данных, то же самое.
Ajax загрузка изображений так же не работает.Может кто знает, в чем причина?